# No desktop environment while nomodeset is disabled

Tags: ubuntu, grub, gnome, desktop-environments

Desktop environment won't start while `GRUBCMDLINELINUX_DEFAULT` is set to `nomodeset`.
While it's disabled Gnome starts but without some features like brightness controll or external display detection.

My configuration:

- Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
- Dell Vostro 3580
- Video Card AMD Radeon 520
- [full spec](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/us/en/19/vostro-15-3580-laptop/vostro_3580_setupandspec/system-specifications?guid=guid-ab67ed37-0818-4592-a25c-f04b3a73c18d&lang=en-us)

Answer (score 0):

That's normal. Most modern Linux GPU drivers [**require**](https://patchwork.kernel.org/patch/10318309/) kernel mode-setting (KMS), i.e. the thing that you're disabling via 'nomodeset' – they no longer support the old method of having Xorg bypass the kernel and directly access the hardware.

(The 'radeon' driver for older GPUs had the userspace mode-setting support removed 8 years ago, and the 'amdgpu' driver for modern GPUs never supported it at all.)

With `nomodeset` you're limited to just the 'vesa' driver with no GPU acceleration, and from what I remember, GNOME refuses to start when using it.